# for loop within if condition

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

So, I currently work on an OOP flow chart project.

Point here is that I want to make sure that the program doesn't draw 2 shapes over each others "As well as for window boundaries", so I should give an IF CONDITION, such that within it, the Program draws in the interface !

Here's a part of my code.

```
 case  ADD_START:
         pO->PrintMessage("Action: add start statement, Click anywhere in the drawing Area");
         Statement*statS;
         pIn->GetPointClicked(P);   
         if ( (for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFigures; i++)
         { //Test
            i == NumOfFigures;
         } ) 
             && (P.x>30) && (P.x< UI.width-(30+UI.ELLIPSE_R1)) && (P.y>2*UI.TlBrWdth+3) 
         && (P.y<UI.height - (UI.StBrWdth+UI.ELLIPSE_R2)) )
             {   
                 statS=new Start();
                 statS->setPoint(P);
                 statS->DrawStatement(pO,pIn);
                 pStat[NumOfFigures] = statS;
                 NumOfFigures++;
             }
      break;
```

Here you can see that `pStat` is array of pointers to an abstract class `Statement`, however, I want to add the address of the shapes drawn at the run-time into that array of pointers, so that withing the `if` condition I could create a `for` loop to check upon each shape in that array with the boundaries of it as to check that P (which is a point)

```
P.x != pStat[NumOfFigure]->x;
```

But the problem here that it gives me an error for the `for` loop inside the `if` statement, saying that

```
ERROR : Expected an expression "
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Wait, what? It's not entirely clear why you're adding a for loop inside an if condition. What is that if condition testing?

Comment: It's not very clear for my what you try to express with `if ( (for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFigures; i++)`, but why not just doing it the other way round?

Comment: You need to rethink the solution and what you want to do. A `for` statement is just that, a *statement*, and can't ever be used as an *expression* which is what `if` expects as condition.

Comment: If it's not clear, I will try to make it clear, simply I want that when it enters the IF condition, to TRAVERSE the shapes within the array 'by a loop' and check for the boundaries !

Comment: @user3054349 I still don't get it. Why not having this `for` loop to traverse all those shapes, and put the boundaries check inside. You don't need to shout on me BTW, OK!

Comment: Supposing that was syntactically valid, what would you expect the value of `for(int i = 0; i < NumOfFigures; i++) { i == NumOfFigures; }` to be?

Comment: Yeah, long time ago !

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are following is invalid syntax to compare *set of values in loop*

You can test for `NumOfFigures` in separate loop and maintain some `flag` variable, and use that variable to compare in `if` condition

```
bool flag=true;
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfFigures; i++)
{ 
    //Test
    if(i != figuresArray[i]){  //here you'l need to use your array from where you want to compare values
        flag=false;
        break;// its not matching, so break loop to test for further values
    }
}

//use flag variable in your if condition
if (flag==true && (P.x>30) && (P.x< UI.width-(30+UI.ELLIPSE_R1)) && (P.y>2*UI.TlBrWdth+3) 
     && (P.y<UI.height - (UI.StBrWdth+UI.ELLIPSE_R2)) )
         {   
             statS=new Start();
             statS->setPoint(P);
             statS->DrawStatement(pO,pIn);
             pStat[NumOfFigures] = statS;
             NumOfFigures++;
         }
```

Comment: Alternatively, put the for-loop logic in a function returning `bool`.

Comment: I would use `bool` and a bit more meaningful name for `flag`, but otherwise I think your answer fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add `loop` in any conditional statement. The concept is you can check any condition and if it is true do something, if not, do some other thing.

```
if( /*expression*/){

  //do  something, including method call, looping construct etc.
}
else if( /*another condition*/){
  //do some other thing
}
 //..... other condition
else{
  // do something
}
```

**EDIT**

To write `loop` inside the `if` block:

```
if( condition ){
 for( int i=0;i<NumOfFigures;i++)
 {
  statS=new Start();
  statS->setPoint(P);
  statS->DrawStatement(pO,pIn);
  pStat[i] = statS; // should be i , not numOfFigures
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so how can I check for my array ?

I want it to enter the array from 0 to the NumOfFigures and check for every shape inside the array, get it ?